# error: initializer element is not constant

Tags: c, mmap

```
int * const front  = mmap(0, sizeof(int),    PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,           MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
int * const back   = mmap(0, sizeof(int),    PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0); 
int * const buffer = mmap(0, sizeof(int)*50, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
```

I am getting the following error: **"error: initializer element is not constant"**

How do I remove it?
I know it won't work if I do something like `int a[b];`, but why is it happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't said, but it's pretty likely that you're working in C, not C++, and that these are variables with static duration?  In C, you can *only* intialize a static variable with something that is a *compile-time* constant expression.  A function-call is not a compile-time constant expression.